# Keeping Qt translations up to date

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cmake

I am working on a C++ application, that uses the Qt library for implementing the GUI (we use cmake files to generate projects for VS). Lately, we are dealing with the internationalization of the application by using built-in Qt's features ([Qt Linguist](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-index.html)). The translation process is simple and straightforward and works great. The Qt Linguist tool can be used by a professional translator to translate files, automatically generated by Qt's tools (lupdate, lrelease).

Because applications are typically never really finished (upgrades, fixes, ...), I am wondering what is the best practice to ensure that all the translation files are always up to date. Is it better to have a person assigned to it or somehow automate it via post-build / pre-commit scripts? Is there some tool that might be useful?

Comment: You should reword the question a bit to avoid it getting closes as *primarily opinion based* or *too broad*. It should be possible to give a single provably correct answer.

Comment: One best practice is not to change the original (supposedly English) in-code strings which are propagated to UI and translated. Or doing so very rarely when absolutely necessary. It's similar to the best practice of not breaking APIs...

Answer (score 2):

We used the QT translator in my previous job. the up-to-date check was poorly done at that time but few things I'm doing in my current job may help:

- If I remember well, the string you define in code will be the default value if not precised in translator, so maybe you should define a default format like "MISSING TRANSLATION - ". So it will be easily detected by QA
- If you have some UI automated testing, adding new tests should include testing the translated strings of the application. Then a failing testcase should help you detect those missing messages (It's what I do today, my language file is in XML and my automation tool automatically compare strings from xml to the message from UI in all supported languages)
- You may have a pre-check script in your versionning tool. For example if the modifications contain a SetToolTip call, you may guess that a modification in translator is also needed... (just an idea, it can becomes really annoying if having a clean translation is time consuming).